# Apiplatform paginator

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com, paginator

I have entity Restaurant with Lat and Lng coordinates

Next I have repository method

```
findNear($lat, $lng) {
    $qb = ...
        ->addSelect("ST_Distance_Sphere(
            point($request->lat, request->lng), 
            point(restaurant.lat, restaurant.lng)) as dist")
   ;

   $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
        ->setMaxResults($request->getPerPage())
    ;
    $qb->addCriteria($criteria);

    $doctrinePaginator = new DoctrinePaginator($qb);
    return new ApiPlatformPaginator($doctrinePaginator);
}
```

And finally getting response like this:

```
{
    "0": {
      "id": 212,
      "lat": 41.394457,
      "lng": 2.1695479
    },
   "dist": "71.45450572744384"
}
```

But I need smth like this:

```
    {
      "id": 212,
      "lat": 41.394457,
      "lng": 2.1695479,
      "dist": "71.45450572744384"
    }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add those columns to the select to generate something like the following?

```
{
    "0": {
      "id": 212,
      "lat": 41.394457,
      "lng": 2.1695479
    },
   "id": 212,
   "lat": 41.394457,
   "lng": 2.1695479,
   "dist": "71.45450572744384"
}
```